# Reusable Linq to XML methods to filter my query results

Tags: c#, xml, linq, facebook

I'm trying to make an facebook application where i can manage my friends. Now i'm making some kind of advanced search. I use FQL and LINQ to XML to fit my search.

But i want my search methods to be reusable. So i can combine multiple filters.

Here's my idea:

```
 private var friends;


 public setFriends(XDocument doc)
        {
            friends = (from usr in doc.Descendants("user")

                     select new User
                     {
                         name = usr.Element("name").Value,
                         email = usr.Element("email").Value,
                         pic = usr.Element("pic_square").Value,
                         city = usr.Element("city").Value,


                     });

        return friends;

    }



public void filterFriendsByName() 
    {
        friends = // some code to filter my previous results by name
    }

 public  void filterFriendsByCity() 
    {
        friends = // some code to filter friends by city
    }

//more filters
```

As you can see, i'm still missing some code here. I don't know if i still can modify my query from here. I hope you can tell me how i could do this. Or else point me in the right direction to make this possible.

Thank you!

Comment: Your setFriends has a return statement, but no return type defined.  Additionally, if you're setting a member variable (friends) you don't need to return it.  Finally, you can't define private var friends.  Because you can't define an anonymous type without initializing it.  So if you had private IEnumberable<Friends> friends that would be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is pretty messed up and won't compile yet. But when you clean it up and correct errors, at last you'll see that `friends` variable will get type `IEnumerable<User>`. After that, you can continue filtering in your filterFriendsByName method, simply as this.

```
public void filterFriendsByName(string name) 
{
    return friends.Where(x=> x.name == name);
}
```

`friends` will not be changed, but method above will return filtered Friends By Name. Same for city

Comment: Yeah, i just simplified my query to be more understandble here. Thx for the reply, i'll try it immediatly. I hope I can mark this as an answer. Because it's little more complicate because i'm working with multiple nested select statements. I hope i can use your solution also for the nested queries.

Comment: No matter how much nested selects you've got - it'll work. This's called chaining. First filter is applied when you call setFriends. The filterFriendsByName adds another filter chain and so on. When evaluating of IEnumerable starts, it'll evaluate chains one by one. see [Query Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx)